# Postgres connection issue

Tags: postgresql, macos, hosts

I installed and started my Postgres database with brew (on my Mac). I also defined an entry in my `/etc/hosts` file (I tried both with `127.0.0.1 postgres` and with  `postgres`).

However, when I try

```
psql -h postgres -U postgres -p 5432
```

I cannot connect

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused.

However, when I try with

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432
```

I can connect. What is needed to be able to connect with: `psql -h postgres -U postgres -p 5432`

Comment: Looks like your hosts file is wrong. Can you ping to postgres?

Comment: I guess this is an OS-related question, not a PSQL-related one. If your system resolves the address ```postgres``` to ```localhost```, you should be able to connect in such way.

Comment: What happens if you run `ping postgres`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your PostgreSQL server is willing to accept tcp/ip connections on port 5432.

In your PostgreSQL configuration file check these values.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

Comment: Thanks - that enabled me to connect with either postgres or localhost as the hostname.